# MVC mini profiler - manually adding step

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

I have lots of little actions (10-30 per page) and they're part of a recursive call, so I can't easily count them as a single step in the profiler. I get 30 short and distinct counters when I only need the total.

Is there a simple and straightforward way of manually adding a step to the mini profiler? or get it to sum up steps with the same name?

Also, is it possible to somehow put textual information there, not just timings?

Answer (score 2):

I needed this as well, so I made this little thing. It works quite well.
A lot of useful properties in MiniProfiler are internal or similar, so some code is duplicated from the MiniProfiler source. Also note that since it's meant for inner loops it does not round to 1/10 millisecond.

```
public class GroupTiming : IDisposable
{
    private Timing _timing;
    private MiniProfiler _profiler;
    private readonly Stopwatch _sw;
    private Decimal? _previousDuration;

    public GroupTiming( MiniProfiler profiler, Timing timing )
    {
        _timing = timing;
        _previousDuration = _timing.DurationMilliseconds ?? 0;
        _timing.DurationMilliseconds = null;
        _profiler = profiler;
        _profiler.Head = _timing;
        _sw = new Stopwatch();
        _sw.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timing.DurationMilliseconds = _previousDuration + ((decimal)(1000 * _sw.ElapsedTicks) / Stopwatch.Frequency);
        _profiler.Head = _timing.ParentTiming;
    }
}

public static class MiniProfilerExtensions
{
    public static IDisposable StepGroup( this MiniProfiler profiler, string name )
    {
        return profiler == null ? null : profiler.StepGroupImpl( name );
    }

    private static IDisposable StepGroupImpl( this MiniProfiler profiler, string name )
    {
        Timing timing = null;

        if( profiler.Head.Children != null )
        {
            timing = profiler.Head.Children.SingleOrDefault( _ => _.Name == name );
        }

        if( timing == null )
        {
            using( timing = new Timing( profiler, profiler.Head, name ) ) { }
        }

        return new GroupTiming( profiler, timing );
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added support for nesting

Answer (score 0):

You want to "wrap" your recursive calls inside of a using statement. Something like this:

```
using (profiler.Step("Step A"))
    { 
        // something recursive here
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
```

The "Step A" will be the total of your calls. Inside of that using statement you can do whatever you want. The "Step A" can be whatever information you want. You could put any string value in there and it will show up in the profiler. You can also add simple textual information by just doing a "step" without the using.

```
MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Some code after this");
```

That will just insert one line into the profiler output window. I've used that for spitting out exceptions or other debug information.

Comment: I don't want to wrap the entire thing, I just want to measure how long a specific piece of code inside the recursive method takes to run. I suppose I can just measure it myself and then add a step with the timing in the step name... but then it will always be in the trivial section, have incorrect timing, etc... I hoped there's a clean way to do it

Comment: I played around with this a bit today and I couldn't find a clean way to do what you want. You can manually set a timing's duration with children, but it messes with the nested hierarchy and the actual duration. Based on my tests it would show up in the "trivial" section anyways because it comes out with a negative duration then. I'd suggest submitting it as a feature request here: http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/list